# JDOM BPMN parsing jdom

Tags: xml, sax, bpmn, jdom

i want to parse my BPMN.xml file with JDOM.
So, first of all i'm extracting data with SAX,
the problem is BPMN.xml has the folowing format:

```
 <bpmn2:process id="process_2" name="Default Process" isExecutable="false">
```

which returns null when having in the .java file:

```
Element process=root.getChild("bpmn2:process")
```

i note that the element "root=document.getRootElement();" does not return null

and when i modify it to

```
<process id="process_2" name="Default Process" isExecutable="false">
```

and

```
Element process=root.getChild("process")
```

it accepts it
so how to deal with that **bpmn2:**  without deleting it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the namespace prefix bpmn2 declared, using a namespace declaration such as `xmlns:bpmn2="http://something/"`? If not, your XML isn't namespace-well-formed, which severely limits your options in processing it.

If there is a namespace declaration, then use

```
Element process=root.getChild("process", "http://something/");
```

where the second argument is the namespace URI associated with the prefix `bpmn2`.